# Is it possible to have the code and pdf preview laid out vertically instead of horizontally in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

The standard layout in overleaf has the code editor and pdf previewer laid out side by side horizontally. Is it possible to change this layout so that the pdf previewer appears on top of the window and the code editor appears underneath it? Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: No, I'm afraid the pane layout is currently fixed and can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, the Overleaf user interface only presents side-by-side documents. My experience has been that the Overleaf developers are very responsive to user requests for new features so I suggest letting Overleaf know you'd like to see a different document layout. They may just implement it! They they implemented a feature I suggested (I'm not intimating my request was the only one for the feature in question.).

Answer (score 0):

My approeach is to open 2 seperate window, on top of each other.
In the one Fire Fox Window i do set the option autocompile.
In the other, change the code.